# Inject services into an ASP.NET MVC app using Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I have Ninject working nicely in an ASP.NET MVC3 web application.  I'd like to do a few things when the app starts using a service I've written.  Does anyone know how I could inject a service into the MvcApplication itself inside the Global.asax.cs?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you using Ninject.Web.Mvc? https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc

Comment: At what point of the application life cycle do you want this service?

Comment: Upon application startup, I'd to load some objects into application scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3

Using this extension the HttpApplication is injected itsself. But only property injection can be used.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I added `[Inject] public IKernel Kernel { get; set; }` to my MvcApplication class, and the property is null when I try to use it in Application_Start.